# How to get index when scrolling WinAPI ListView

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi

I am trying to set up a system where when a user hoverers over a `ListView` item, it causes a red x to appear. The way I have implemented it so far is by catching the `WM_MOUSEHOVER` event and then using the x and y coordinates divided against the total height to find the position in the list of the hovered-over item. Them a variable is set equal to that value and the window is redrawn. Next, in the custom draw function, it checks against that to see if each row is equal to the hovered-over item. If so, I makes the previously white 'X' red. This works fine--until you scroll. The algorithm I used only finds the position on the screen, not the actual index of the item. Is there some way to find the actual index of a `ListView` item with only its position on the screen? For reference, here is some snippets of the code from the relevant functions:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ProjectsListView::listViewProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
{
    ProjectsListView* listView = reinterpret_cast<ProjectsListView*>(dwRefData);
    
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEHOVER:
    {
        int mouseX = LOWORD(lParam);
        int mouseY = HIWORD(lParam);

        float tempYPos = mouseY + listView->fontHeight * .5;

        listView->xShown = round(mouseY / (listView->fontHeight * 2));


        RedrawWindow(listView->getHandle(), NULL, NULL, RDW_INVALIDATE | RDW_UPDATENOW);
        break;
    }

    case  WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        // start tracking
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;
        tme.cbSize = sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT);
        tme.dwFlags = TME_HOVER;
        tme.hwndTrack = hWnd; //This is the handle to the ListView window
        tme.dwHoverTime = 1;

        TrackMouseEvent(&tme);

        break;

    case WM_NOTIFY:
        switch (((LPNMHDR)lParam)->code)
        {

        }
        break;

    }
    

    return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
int ProjectsListView::CustomDraw(LPNMCUSTOMDRAW drawStruct)
{
  
    LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW lvDrawStruct = (LPNMLVCUSTOMDRAW)drawStruct;

    switch (lvDrawStruct->nmcd.dwDrawStage)
    {
    case CDDS_PREPAINT:
        return CDRF_NOTIFYITEMDRAW;

    case CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:

         return CDRF_NOTIFYSUBITEMDRAW;

    case CDDS_SUBITEM | CDDS_ITEMPREPAINT:
    {
       

        switch (lvDrawStruct->iSubItem)
        {
        case 2:
        {   
            if (drawStruct->dwItemSpec / 2 == xShown)
                lvDrawStruct->clrText = RGB(255, 0, 0);
            else
                lvDrawStruct->clrText = RGB(255, 255, 255);
            return CDRF_NEWFONT;
        }

        }

        break;

    }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-hittest) to retrieve an item containing a given point. You don't need to do the math yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass the ListView window, then process `WM_MOUSEMOVE` and send [`LVM_HITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lvm-hittest) to get the index of the list item.

Some code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK ListViewProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LVHITTESTINFO htif;
    POINT pt;
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        htif.pt = pt;
        ScreenToClient(hwnd, &htif.pt);
        int idx = SendMessage(hwnd, LVM_HITTEST, 0, (LPARAM)&htif);  //the index you need
        break;
    }
    }
    return CallWindowProc(oldListViewProc, hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```